# Is there a really easy way to make a live USB in win 8?

Tags: windows-8, live-usb, live-cd

So far I have always used linux distros to create USB live installers, but now the only thing I have is win8. I have tried that Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.1 and it doesnt get me anywhere. Is there a really simple way to make a bootable ubuntu or linuxmint usb drive from win10?

By the way.....the usb drive is almost unrecognzable for win8 since I already have a linux installer on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you'll have to format the USB drive (this should be obvious). [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) is an amazing tool that quickly formats the target and makes a bootable disk for pretty much anything. I highly recommend it.

Comment: that was helpful. Managed to create the lie USB. Cheers.